# How to Cast a IQueryable/IEnumerable result to a custom Model C# EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Lets say that I have a Repository with this function

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Contacts>> GetAll()
 {
     return await _context.Contacts.ToListAsync();
 }
```

Where the Contacts Entity is the same one returning the call. But I didn't want to use the same class because there's some fields that I like to keep out of the call. There's any way that I could "mirror" a second model called "ContactsModel" to return the data without using Anonymous calls like :

```
var result = context.t_validation.Where(a => a.isvalidated == 10).Select(x => new
                {
                    x.date_released,
                    x.utoken,
                    x.Images,
                    x.images_key,
                    x.Type
                });
```

Of putting into a loop and passing to this new Model :

```
foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    decp.Add(new ValidationModel
                    {
                        uToken = item.utoken,
                        Date = item.date_released,
                        Images = bc.Decrypt(item.Images, item.images_key),
                        Type = item.Type
                    });
                }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using custom method to decrypt an image, you will not be able to include it in the query, because EF will not be able to translate it into sql query.

Anonymous approach would be the best one

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Contacts>> GetAll()
{
    var models = await _context
        .Contacts
        .Select(contact => new
        {
            contact.date_released,
            contact.utoken,
            contact.Images,
            contact.images_key,
            contact.Type        
        })
        .ToListAsync()

    return models
        .Select(item => new ValidationModel
        {
            uToken = item.utoken,
            Date = item.date_released,
            Images = bc.Decrypt(item.Images, item.images_key),
            Type = item.Type
        }
        .ToList();   
}
```

Of course you can wrap it with an extension methods, but if you are using this mapping only in one place you don't need to.